# Proof trigamma recurrence relation

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations, gamma-function, digamma-function

How can I prove the digamma and trigamma recurrence relations, $$\psi(x+1)=\psi(x)+\frac{1}{x} \,?$$ 
I tried some advice for common recurrence relations, but it didn't open for me.

Comment: Assuming that your definition of $\psi$ is $\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma=\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}$, just apply $\frac{d}{dx}\log(\cdot)$ to both sides of $$ \Gamma(x+1)=x\cdot \Gamma(x).$$ Anyway, $\psi$ is the *di*gamma function; the *tri*gamma function is $\psi'$.

Comment: Exactly as Jack says ... & see this ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the Gamma function property 
$$\Gamma(x + 1) = x \, \Gamma(x)$$
then by differentiation with respect to $x$ of the logarithm of the relation it is seen that
\begin{align}
\ln(\Gamma(x + 1)) &= \ln(\Gamma(x)) + \ln(x) \\
\frac{\Gamma^{'}(x+1)}{\Gamma(x + 1)} &= \frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)} + \frac{1}{x}.
\end{align}
Using the defined relation for the digamma function, namely, $\Gamma(x) \, \psi(x) = \Gamma'(x)$ then the digamma relation is
$$\psi(x+1) = \psi(x) + \frac{1}{x}.$$ 
Applying differentiation again leads to the following trigamma relation:
\begin{align}
\psi'(x+1) = \psi'(x) - \frac{1}{x^{2}}.
\end{align}